# Is there a way to force cassandra to select rows even if it exceeds the maximum tombstone settings?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, tombstone

I'm using Cassandra 3.11, I have a table which contains a lot of tombstones. This is normal as periodically (once per day) I need to update big sets of data. Some data will never change, but there are updates. So it happens once in a while that I have many tombstones read during some maintenance periods. One of my select statement often will return with a failure status, the reason is the maximum amount of tombstones reached.

Is there a way to force cassandra to execute one specific select statement, even though the maximum Tombstone is reached? For my maintenance programs that would be very useful. I guess something similar to "allow filtering"...

Comment: can you specifiy the no of nodes you are using?

Comment: We have 10 nodes.